# Passing variable to partials in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm trying to pass a variable to a partials but it doesn't render the passed variable and html code -- is there a way to do this?

e.g.

```
{{>sayHello text="Hello <b>{{firstName}}</b>!"}}
```

the partial prints `Hello <b>{{firstName}}</b>!` instead of Hello **Efe**!

Comment: You are getting that output because the value of `text` is a string literal - it is _not_ a template that Handlebars will interpolate. If you want Handlebars to do interpolation, you need to include your Handlebars expressions (`{{ }}`) within templates and partials. In this case, it looks like you should move the value you are assigning to `text` to the body of your partial.

Comment: Thanks @76484 , could you show me  sample codes i can do this (passing it as not a string)?

Comment: I have created an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/xrq68gdn/